# Integrate $\int2x^3\cos(x^2)dx$ without using integration by parts or substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to show that
$$\int2x^3\cos(x^2)dx=x^2\sin(x^2)+\cos(x^2)+C$$
without using integration by parts or substitution and I have absolutely no idea how to do that without those tools. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing whoever set you this problem wants you to remember the relationship between differentiation and antidifferentiation.

Comment: Do you have to show this equality or to calculate the integral? For the first problem you can show that the derivative of the RHS is the function under the integral.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have to calculate the integral, not solve the equality, that would be too easy after all!

Comment: I was trying to experiment with antidifferentiation a bit but I still can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that:
$$(\cos (x^2))'=-2x\sin (x^2); \ \ (\sin (x^2))'=2x\cos (x^2).$$
The integral:
$$\begin{align}\int2x^3\cos(x^2)dx&=\int2x\cos (x^2)\cdot x^2\ dx=\\
&=\int (\sin (x^2))'\cdot x^2 \ dx=\\
&=\int (\sin (x^2))'\cdot x^2 +2x\sin (x^2)-2x\sin (x^2)\ dx=\\
&=\int (\sin (x^2))'\cdot x^2 +(x^2)'\sin (x^2)+(\cos (x^2))'\ dx=\\
&=\int (\sin (x^2)\cdot x^2)'+(\cos (x^2))' \ dx=\\
&=\int (x^2\cdot \sin (x^2))' \ dx+\int (\cos (x^2))' \ dx=\\
&=x^2\sin(x^2)+\cos(x^2)+C,\end{align}$$
where it was used the product rule:
$$(uv)'=u'v+uv' \iff u'v+uv'=(uv)'.$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int2x^3\cos(x^2)dx
&= \int2x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{4n}}{(2n)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\int x^{4n+3}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2(n+1)(2n)!}x^{4n+4} + C \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n+1)}{(2n+2)!}x^{4n+4} + C \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n+2)}{(2n+2)!}x^{4n+4}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+2)!}x^{4n+4} + C \\
&= x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{4n+2}-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{4n} + C \\
&= x^2\sin(x^2)+\cos(x^2)+C_1
\end{align}

Comment: IMO the best answer, as you are not using the product rule for derivatives nor the chain rule, which are mirroring integration by parts and by substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If we differentiate an expression like $P(x)\cos x^2$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $p$, we end-up with a term $P'(x)\cos x^2$ where $P$ is of degree $p-1$, and a term $-2xP(x)\sin x^2$, giving degree $p+1$ and with a sine instead of a cosine.

This leads us to try $$(x^2\sin x^2)'=2x\sin x^2+2x^3\cos x^2.$$

Now we have an extra term $2x\sin x^2$ and following the same logics, we try

$$(\cos x^2)'=-2x\sin x^2$$ and bingo !